# MPI_RECV receives 0 value when a variable is used as the source, but recieves proper value when the source number is hard coded

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am trying to receive a variable from multiple processed as part of a DO loop.  However, the value of the variable is 0 after the operation if I use a variable to represent the processor number.  It works fine if I put the processor number in directly.  Oddly enough, the exact same code works fine earlier in the program.  Any thoughts on my problem?

```
  DO s = 1,numproc-1,1
        CALL MPI_RECV( numZERO, 1, MPI_INTEGER, s, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierr )
        WRITE(*,*)'s',s,'numZERO',numZERO
  END DO
```

gives:

```
  s   1   numZERO   0
  s   2   numZERO   0 ...
```

when it is coded:

```
  CALL MPI_RECV( numZERO, 1, MPI_INTEGER, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierr )
  WRITE(*,*)'1 numZERO',numZERO
  CALL MPI_RECV( numZERO, 1, MPI_INTEGER, 2, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierr )
  WRITE(*,*)'2 numZERO',numZERO
```

I get

```
  1 numZERO   1
  2 numZERO   2 ...
```

`s` is an integer.

Comment: are you absolutely sure s is integer and not implicit real?

Comment: Have you checked the value of `ierr`? See link for list of error codes: http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Recv.html

Comment: Can you post the code somewhere (perhaps http://pastebin.com/)? That obviously should not happen, and there is nothing wrong with the code you posted, so the trouble must be somewhere else... In any case, as **brady** suggested, I would also check `ierr`.

Answer (score 0):

"ierr" is going to be useless.  Fortran MPI implementations don't return anything there by default.  They understand that you are not going to check it, so the writers bomb with an error rather than passing something useful.  You can request that MPI return errors.

You might check the "status" because that on very rare occasions is useful.

"S" should be an integer of the right size (integer*4 usually).  That is all that I could think is wrong.